# Predictions receiving in Unknown (8)[e,e,e,e,e,e,e,e] format from TensorflowJS Mobilenet

Tags: machine-learning, python, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection

I have trained a mobilenet on diamond images to count diamonds in broswer. I then converted the SavedModel format to TFJS format. I have the following code in my JS file.

```
async function initialize() {
try{
    model = await tf.loadGraphModel('trained-model/model.json');
}catch(e) {
   console.log("The model is not loaded") 
}

classifierElement.style.display = 'block';
loaderElement.style.display = 'none';

document.getElementById('predict').addEventListener('click', () => predictOnClick());
}

async function predictOnClick () {

  const imageElement = document.getElementById('img');
  let tensorImg = tf.browser.fromPixels(imageElement,3).cast('int32').resizeNearestNeighbor([640, 640]);//.expandDims();
  const t4d=tensorImg.expandDims(0);
  t4d.print() 
  data = await t4d.data()

  prediction = model.executeAsync(t4d).data().then(prediction=> { 
  console.log("FULL STRUCTURE",prediction)})
```

I am getting the following in console output
[image]

The tensorflow model Non-Javascript version returns the following dict

```
['detection_multiclass_scores', 'detection_classes', 'detection_boxes', 'raw_detection_boxes', 'detection_scores', 'raw_detection_scores', 'detection_anchor_indices', 'num_detections'])
```

So how do I obtain the scores and detection boxes data from the TFJS model rather than (8)[e,e,e,e,e,e,e,e] format?

Thanks

Comment: What data is contained in each of the `e` records? I.e. what do you see when you click open one of the 8 arrows?

Comment: @Oxbowerce, when I open for example 4 which i studied and came to know that those are the detection_scores, but i am getting the following: 
dataId: {id: 1320}
dtype: "float32"
id: 841
isDisposedInternal: false
kept: false
rankType: "2"
scopeId: 783
shape: (2) [1, 1000]
size: 1000
strides: [1000]
isDisposed: (...)
rank: (...)
__proto__: Object

Comment: And when is console predictions[4], then it consoles the complete array of the predictions.

Comment: So if example 4 holds the `detection_scores` then each example links back to the list you get back in the non-js version, which is what you want right? Also have a look at [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59575812/how-to-interpret-the-output-of-object-detection-model-in-tensorflow-js).

Comment: Everytime I restart the server, this time its 4, then sometimes its 6 that holds the prediction_scores. How to resolve this ? COCOSSD has something like prediction.scores, predictions.bbox. How to know about MobileNet